# Laravel and DataTables.net

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datatable, datatables, laravel-7

I am beginner in Laravel.
I use in my project Laravel 7. I use yajra/laravel-datatables in my project.

I have this code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered data-table    ">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Tytuł</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th width="100px">Akcja</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


$(function () {
            var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "{{ route('tabelka.tabelka2') }}",
                columns: [
                    {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
                    // {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'title', name: 'title'},
                    {data: 'enable', name: 'enable'},
                    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                ]
            });
        });
```

and controller:

```
public function tabelka2(Request $request)
    {
//        return Datatables::of(Page::query())->make(true);
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Page::get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){

                    //$btn .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>';
                    $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm"></a> ';
                    $btn .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm"></a> ';



                    return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
    }
```

It's work fine.

1. How do I search for columns other than title, enable? I need to search for description and keywords.
2. If enable = 1 - I would like to display "active". Otherwise "inactive"
3. I would like to "pack" the title value in:  ...])}} "> description

Anyone know how to do this? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Im not sure if i understand and i dont have reputation enought to comment. Where does the description comes from? But if you want manipulate the input string or compare with value that are on database i suggest you begin [here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/custom-filter-search-with-laravel-datatables-exampleexample.html) and [here](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/fluent/advance-filter)

2 - You can use editColumn function and check $row value. Something like this:

```
->addIndexColumn()
->editColumn('columnName', function ($row){
    if($row->atributte == 1) 
       return 'true';
    else return 'false';

}
```

3 - Again im not sure if i understand. If you want concaten or manipulate two values that are in database you can use de last tip.

You can see more at [Docs](https://datatables.yajrabox.com)

Comment: thank you for help :) I have migration:Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title', 155);
            $table->string('description', 155)->nullable();
            $table->string('keywords', 155)->nullable();
            $table->longText('content')->nullable();
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->string('slug', 160);
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });

Comment: I show in datable.net: title, id and enable. I want search in title, id, content and keywords